# Not to display SQLPLUS prompt

Tags: linux, bash, oracle, sqlplus, display

I am trying to connect with sqlplus using a bash script. When I execute the script below SQLPLUS banner displayed.

**Below the script:**

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus "/ as sysdba" <<EOF
  set echo off
  set heading off
  spool bind.txt
  select * from DBMS_LOCK_ALLOCATED where name = '$uservar';
  spool off
  exit
EOF
```

**Output of the script**

```
oracle@DMOTA01:~/script> ./before_bind.sh

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Wed Nov 27 11:54:01 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> SQL>   2    3    4  Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
oracle@DMOTA01:~/script>
```

I don't want to display "SQL*Plus: Release 11............. Real Application Testing options" lines. How i can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `-S` to `sqlplus` to switch it in silence mode:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -S "/ as sysdba" <<EOF
  set echo off
  set heading off
  spool bind.txt
  select * from DBMS_LOCK_ALLOCATED where name = '$uservar';
  spool off
  exit
EOF
```